# AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Tags: android, sqlite

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa1d1780
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae494780: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae4b0400)
E/SQLiteLog: (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.harshpatel.asktoaexpert, PID: 14728
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTable(id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, password VARCHAR);
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                  at com.example.harshpatel.asktoaexpert.signupfarmer.SQLiteTableBuild(signupfarmer.java:79)
                  at com.example.harshpatel.asktoaexpert.signupfarmer$1.onClick(signupfarmer.java:52)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, usage of sqlite open helpers aren't encouraged unless you know SQL well. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **specify the column type** of id and a **primary key** has **automatically** a **not null** constraint:

Try

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

instead of

```
id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank u so much my problem solved

Comment: No Problem, please mark the answer as correct then :)